# post to put/patch update on laravel

Tags: laravel, http, routes

I got this html:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/stories/13" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="G9TVapBuoqmBxgnaqHKjfh9KEaYYE62Z7XEJdSUW">
        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
    <h1>Modifica Storia</h1>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="titolo">Titolo</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="titolo" type="text" value="Titolo" id="titolo">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="incipit">Incipit</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="incipit" cols="50" rows="10" id="incipit">Incipt</textarea>
        </div>

        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Modifica">
</form>
```

generated by blade/laravel functions:

```
{{ Form::model($story, array('route' => array('stories.update', $story->idStories), 'method' => 'POST')) }}
            <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
        <h1>Modifica Storia</h1>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('titolo', 'Titolo') }}
            {{ Form::text('titolo', old('titolo'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('incipit', 'Incipit') }}
            {{ Form::textarea('incipit', old('incipit'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </div>

        {!! Form::submit('Modifica', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

I supposing to put the hidden field "_method" to let laravel form collective works on patch/put methods. I know that works only with GET/POST request.

This is the list of my routes:

```
/workspace/speechToTextStories$ php artisan route:list
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                    | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                      |                  | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth   |
|        | POST      | broadcasting/auth      |                  | Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastController@authenticate               | web        |
|        | POST      | login                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | login                  | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | logout                 |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web        |
|        | POST      | logout                 | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web        |
|        | POST      | password/email         | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset         | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest  |
|        | POST      | password/reset         |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token} | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest  |
|        | POST      | register               |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register               | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | stories                | stories.index    | App\Http\Controllers\StoriesController@index                           | web        |
|        | POST      | stories                | stories.store    | App\Http\Controllers\StoriesController@store                           | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | stories/create         | stories.create   | App\Http\Controllers\StoriesController@create                          | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | stories/{story}        | stories.show     | App\Http\Controllers\StoriesController@show                            | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | stories/{story}        | stories.update   | App\Http\Controllers\StoriesController@update                          | web        |
|        | DELETE    | stories/{story}        | stories.destroy  | App\Http\Controllers\StoriesController@destroy                         | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | stories/{story}/edit   | stories.edit     | App\Http\Controllers\StoriesController@edit                            | web        |
```

After hitting the submit buttons on the edit view im redirect to something like: `url/stories/13`

thats report the 404 errror. It seems that looking for the url in POST that doesnt exist!
Im confused where im wrong? Using resources on route is now deprecated? i build my own route names to make it works maybe?

Comment: Does it 404 before or after it's updated the story?

Comment: Can you add your controller code?

Comment: I found the error in the controller!!!! i was looking for an id that doesnt exist in the inputs! my fault thanks to all!

Comment: run this command and check **composer dump-autoload**